# bootstrap.php.cache in a Symfony 3.4 application

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-2.8, symfony3.x

I am looking to confirm how my app*.php files should be configured with regards to the `bootstrap.php.cache` file.

I have read some conflicting advice on how to treat this file in Symfony 3.0 and above, namely 
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade/new-dir-structure#moving-bootstrap-php-cache and https://gist.github.com/mickaelandrieu/5d27a2ffafcbdd64912f549aaf2a6df9#files-to-move-update-

My understanding is that `bootstrap.php.cache` is required for a performance boost and is only required or recommended in the 'prod' environment. So this leaves me with the following setup:

`app.php`:

```
/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

`app_dev.php`:

```
/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

Previously `$loader` was `/app/autoload.php`, which has been moved to `/vendor` and `/app/bootstrap.php.cache` has been deleted and the DistrubutionBundle is now writing that file to `/var`.

Is this setup correct? (bin/console --env=dev/prod returns no errors)

Comment: What you got looks fine.  The thing to understand is that thanks to php improvements, the bootstrap file is no longer needed.  If you create a fresh app using Symfony Flex then you don't even have one generated.  Looks like you are dealing with legacy code that has been tweaked.  There used to be an app/autoload.php that you seemed to have bypassed.  Which is fine.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for the comment. Feel free to submit this as an answer and I will glady accept. Many thanks.